# how to plot two graphs together while share the same scale of x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot two graph together which share the same x-axis. How can I do that?
My data can be build using codes:

```
df <-structure(list(SDTM_LabN = c("ALP", "AST", "ALT", "AST", "ALT", 
"ALT", "ALP", "AST", "ALP", "AST", "ALP", "ALT", "ALP", "ALP", 
"ALT", "AST", "ALT", "ALT", "ALT", "AST", "AST", "ALP", "AST", 
"ALT", "ALP", "ALP", "AST"), ADY = structure(c(45, 15, 1, 1, 
30, 58, 30, 45, 46, -6, 23, 46, -6, 15, 23, 46, 45, -6, 8, 30, 
58, 58, 23, 15, 8, 1, 8), class = "difftime", units = "days"), 
    result = c(0.841269841269841, 0.578947368421053, 0.625, 0.552631578947368, 
    0.416666666666667, 0.3125, 0.936507936507937, 0.447368421052632, 
    0.634920634920635, 0.657894736842105, 0.873015873015873, 
    0.291666666666667, 0.73015873015873, 0.857142857142857, 0.5, 
    0.447368421052632, 0.479166666666667, 0.625, 0.604166666666667, 
    0.5, 0.526315789473684, 0.849206349206349, 0.526315789473684, 
    0.5, 1.00793650793651, 0.896825396825397, 0.894736842105263
    )), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = "data.frame")

df2<-structure(list(ID = c(101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101), AEDECOD = c("Diarrhoea", 
"Vitreous floaters", "Musculoskeletal pain", "Diarrhoea", "Decreased appetite", 
"Fatigue"), AESTDY = structure(c(101, 74, 65, 2, 33, 27), class = "difftime", units = "days"), 
    AEENDY = structure(c(105, 99, NA, 5, NA, NA), class = "difftime", units = "days")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My plots codes are:

```
ggplot(df, aes(colour=SDTM_LabN)) + 
    geom_line(aes(x=ADY,y=result)) 

ggplot(df2, aes(colour=AEDECOD)) + 
    geom_segment(aes(x=AESTDY, xend=AEENDY, y=AEDECOD, yend=AEDECOD),) +
    xlab("Duration")
```

How can I get sth that looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Try `library(patchwork);  p1 / p2` where `p1` is the first plot and `p2` second

Comment: This package can plot two graphs together, however the x-axis are not at the same scale. Any way to solve that?

Comment: I guess the solution posted below would get you there, right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first make sure to calculate common xmin-xmax to both series.

Then with `patwhwork` a suggested in comments or `cowplot`:

```
xmin <- min(df$ADY ,df2$AESTDY)
xmax <- max(df$ADY ,df2$AESTDY)

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(colour=SDTM_LabN)) + 
        geom_line(aes(x=ADY,y=result)) +
        coord_cartesian(xlim = c(xmin,xmax))


p2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(colour=AEDECOD)) + 
        geom_segment(aes(x=AESTDY, xend=AEENDY, y=AEDECOD, yend=AEDECOD),) +
        xlab("Duration") + 
        coord_cartesian(xlim = c(xmin,xmax))

library(cowplot)
plot_grid(plotlist = list(p1,p2),align='v',ncol=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to overlay those two plot? left y-axis for plot one and right y-axis for plot2?

Comment: Perhap this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49498838/13513328